# Running and killing processes in QT C++ via button press

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, process, qprocess

I am trying to write a GUI, that when a button is pressed, will either start or stop a process.  Currently, my code won't even start the process, and I am stuck to why that is.  The button clicks and the text changes, but the process doesn't execute and no error messages occur.  This is the code for the button slot in the QMainWindow object:

```
void clickedSlot(){   
        QString s = "Record";
        //switch between record and stop
        if(s!=((QPushButton*)sender())->text()){
            ((QPushButton*)sender())->setText("Record");
    process->kill();
    process->waitForFinished();
    delete process;
        }else{
            ((QPushButton*)sender())->setText("Stop");
    process = new QProcess(this);
    QString executable = "./record";
            process->start(executable);
    process->waitForStarted();
        }
};
```

Any help to why the QProcess doesn't start and how to stop it after would be greatly appreciated.  I do have a #include  at the top of the code

Comment: You should check QProcess::error() and QProcess::state() for more info.  You should also check the return value of QProcess::waitForStarted()

Comment: Check `waitForStarted` return value. It should be false if process has failed to start. Make sure that `record` executable is in the app's working directory.

Comment: What platform are you using OSX or Linux?

Comment: As JRG says. And `errorString()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the executable path you are (not) starting.
Try again by making sure that:

- you give an absolute path to [process->start(absolutePath, arguments)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#start).
- you make sure [process->waitForStarted()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#waitForStarted) returns true.
- you can retrieve the output of your program using process->readAllStandardOutput() and process->readAllStandardError() to debug it.